# Connect asp net project to a MantisBT tracker

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mantis

I have an asp net project and I have to add some issues to a Mantis tracker affter a login. What is the best way to do it? JS or C#? I found a couple of libraries (like Mantis-JS), but I see that there is no documentation and I don't understand what I should do.

Comment: Have you tried Googling? You haven't provided any code or even told us what issues you are facing. Please provide us more information so we can best assist you.

Comment: Yes. I found a JS script (mantis-js), but there the web site seems down, so I have no idea on how I can use it and a c# client, MantisDotNetClient, but it's old and there is no info on what it does. So I was wondering if there is something recent to connect to a tracker and send data.

Answer (score 0):

[MantisDotNetClient](https://github.com/mantishub/MantisDotNetClient) seems to be what you are looking for. And of course you can always roll your own client by importing the WSDL. I'm not familiar with .Net development but it should be pretty standard stuff.